# Debian does not shut down interface with ip link set ... down

Tags: networking, debian, virtualization, vlan, bonding

I have a really specific question for a trunk-testing environment. I have this network setup:

```
+------------+               +------------+
|            |    +-----+    |            |
|       eth0 +----+ br0 +----+ eth0       |
|            |    +-+---+    |            |
| Guest1     |      |        |     Guest2 |
|            |    +-----+    |            |
|       eth1 +----+ br1 +----+ eth1       |
|            |    +---+-+    |            |
+------------+      | |      +------------+
                  +-+-+--+
                  | Host |
                  +------+
```

The KVM host serves two bridge for the guest machines (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet manual
  bridge_ports none
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_stp off

auto br1
iface br1 inet manual
  bridge_ports none
  bridge_fd 0
  bridge_stp off
```

The guest machines connect to the switches with this configuration:

```
# Actual interfaces
allow-hotplug eth0 eth1
iface eth0 inet manual
iface eth1 inet manual

# Internet facing network
auto eth0.100 eth1.100
iface eth0.100 inet manual
iface eth1.100 inet manual

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
  bond_mode active-backup
  bond_miimon 200
  bond_downdelay 200
  bond_updelay 200
  # Something I found to make the active secondary slave listening
  post-up echo 1 > /sys/devices/virtual/net/bond0/bonding/all_slaves_active
  slaves eth0.100 eth1.100

auto bond0.1
  address 10.110.0.10x
  netmask 255.255.0.0

# Please don't ask why the three vlan is needed.
# The bonding works only if these three are defined :\
```

Now my problem is the following:

The default primary slave is the eth0.100 interface on both guest. If I shut down the primary slave with the following command

```
$ ip link set eth0.100 down
```

The link goes down according to "ip link", the bond changes the primary slave, yet packets are accepted on the inactive interface.
(I found it out by running "tshark -i eth1.100" and only the ping-reply messages were shown.)

If I close down the interface on the host machine, the whole communication stops between the guests. Even the bond does not recognize the change.

Additional info:

- I have no IPTables/EBTables rule to block packages on this interface
- I know the broadcast mode would help with all my problems, although I think it makes the communication between the two guests bloated. I'd rather not use that option.

Questions:

- Why doesn't "ip link set ... down" close down the link?
- Is it possible, that meddling with all_slaves_active somehow interferes with the interface status?
- Is there any option I might slipped over, which makes the active-backup aware of the interface change?
- (And why do I need the three VLAN to make the bonding work?)

Any reply is appreciated.